# How can i know all the devices connected to my TP-Link router using SNMP?

Tags: snmp

I am trying to planning to write a script that keeps a log of each device that connected to my Wi-Fi router so as to know the daily time based usage for my project.

How do I do this? I researched and got to know `SNMP` protocol can be used for the same.

My router is `TP-Link Archer C5 AC1200`.

Any leads will help.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the device manual to see if it supports SNMP and what management objects you can use. If not, then this question won't be valid.

Comment: The device supports SNMP, how do i know about the management objects?

Comment: If the manual does not talk about the details, contact its vendor for more information. That's not something SO can answer.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you.